# Classify datasets in C# - how to do it?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, design-patterns, classification, flags

I have a question about classification of data. I suppose it's like Google's PageRank's goal: how to classify a query so that we return the best matching result?

I have simplified a scenario to illustrate my business problem.

Suppose I have some houses on the market and suppose I use Enums as "flags" or "options" to assign to my house objects.
This example is not about good design, but about the programmatic solution to favor one house over the other based on the demand of the customer.

As you can see at the bottom, the customers will often mix/match many of the same wishes. So I need to find out which house is the best match without resorting to a thousand if/else or switch statements.

Is it possible?

**The flags/options:**

```
enum RoomTypes
{
    Bathroom,
    Bedroom,
    Livingroom,
    Study
}

enum Nearby
{
    School,
    Hospital,
    ShoppingMall,
    Park,
    Trainstation
}

enum Features
{
    Airconditioning,
    Garage,
    Garden,
    Storage,
    Basement
}
```

**The class:**

```
class House
{
    public IEnumerable<RoomTypes> RoomTypes {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Nearby> Nearby {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Features> Features {get; set;}
}
```

==============

We have 2 available houses:

```
var bigHouse = new House 
{ 
    RoomTypes = new IEnumerable<RoomTypes>{ RoomTypes.Bathroom, RoomTypes.Bedroom, RoomTypes.Study };
    Nearby = new IEnumerable<Nearby>{ Nearby.School, Nearby.Park, Nearby.ShoppingMall };
    Features = new IEnumerable<Features>{ Features.Airconditioning, Features.Storage, Features.Garden };
}

var smallHouse = new House 
{ 
    RoomTypes = new IEnumerable<RoomTypes>{ RoomTypes.Livingroom, RoomTypes.Bedroom };
    Nearby = new IEnumerable<Nearby>{ Nearby.Trainstation };
    Features = new IEnumerable<Features>{ Features.Airconditioning };
}
```

==============

**Use case:**
*A client applies for a house based on options.*

**Client A:**

- **RoomTypes**: Bathroom, Bedroom
- **Nearby**: Park, ShoppingMall, School
- **Features**: Airconditioning, Basement, Garden

**Client B:**

- **RoomTypes**: Bedroom, Bathroom
- **Nearby**: ShoppingMall, Trainstation
- **Features**: Airconditioning, Garage

The question is now, how do I rate the applications based on the available houses?

Comment: `how do I rate the applications based on the available houses`, I guess that depends on what raises and lowers the rating. What makes the rating of one application higher than the next? This is your domain, it's your calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a difficult question to explain in such a short space. What you will need to do is a bit linear algebra.

For all these feature create a vector representing what houses you have available

```
House = [1,0,1,0..........] {attributes are bed room, bathroom, Near park, Airconditioning etc }
```

Create a smiliar vector for Client's Requirement.

Take a Dot product between client requirement's vector and vector of houses that is available to you. The house with largest dot product is closest house that matches your client requirement.

Can you tell why :)

Why dot product with largest is value should be chosen ? As you can see when attributes match the multiplication would be 1 else 0 .

Comment: I am accepting your answer, because you put me on the right track. I'm discovering the wonderful world of Vector Space Models, which is exctly what I need :) Thanks.

Comment: yes, this example was the most trivial example that I could had given you.